# Invalid SQL Query - Non-boolean type specified

Tags: sql-server

I'm not a SQL Server expert. I am trying to execute a query. The query relies on a function to split a CSV and doing a join on a table. Its a pretty basic query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
 [Order]
WHERE
 dbo.ConvertIDListToTable('1,2,3,4', ',') l INNER JOIN Order o ON l.item=o.ID
```

When I execute the query, I get the following error:

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'l'.
```

What am I doing wrong? This has to be something syntactical. I keep staring at it, but everythign looks correct to me. Thank you.

Comment: What is `ConvertIDListToTable`? What does it return?

Comment: A table with a column called "item". With the example above, 4 records are returned. Record 1: 1, Record 2: 2 Record 3: 3, and Record 4: 4.

Comment: Does the function return a table of ints or a table of strings? Is ID an int or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically, your `INNER JOIN`s should come before your `WHERE` statement, and in addition, you don't need the `WHERE` statement here.

Not knowing the exact code of `ConvertIDListToTable` is a hindrance, but assuming it returns a table, I think you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ConvertIDListToTable('1,2,3,4', ',') l 
INNER JOIN Order o ON l.item=o.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a JOIN in a WHERE clause. It is indeed a syntax problem.

Look at SQL Server SELECT syntax : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

You should JOIN before the WHERE clause. If you want more help for your query please clarify what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this query structure is from mysql

In SQL Server you would write it like this:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
 [Order] o 
 Inner join dbo.ConvertIDListToTable('1,2,3,4', ',') l
   ON l.item=o.ID
```